# Typescript decorators for @OnCall and @OnRequest firebase functions?

Tags: typescript, typescript-decorator

I'm trying to write some method decorators to use with firebase functions in typescript but i'm a bit confused on the syntax and what I've tried so far isn't working.

I'd like to have methods in my class, for example:

```
@OnCall('europe-west1')
@Wrapper([errorHandler, validateSomething])
doSomething(data, context) {
// doing stuff in the function
}
```

and the final result to be:

```
const doSomething = functions.region(<REGION PARAM>).https.onCall((data, context) => {

errorHandler() {

  validateSomething() {

    DECORATEDFUNCTION()
}

});
```

Now the wrapper part isn't as critical at first although desirable. So far I've tried various variations of this:

```
export function OnCall(region: string, name: string, target: any): MethodDecorator {
    return target => {
        //
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone stumbling upon this, I ended up writing a few decorators and a function that consumes them to get the indended result, I have, in the end, abandoned the idea as it seems to go agains the purpose of serverless functions and essentially just trying to mimmick REST endpoints with standalone functions.

[The github project can be found here.](https://github.com/decorfn) Where there's also an example project using the decorators.